# Get characters after a given word

Tags: .net, powershell

How to find a certain word in a file name and get some characters after it?

**For example:**

File 01 - Vertical - Day 04 - **Model 01-01**

File 02 - **Model 01-02** - Day 02

How forever find the word `Model` in a file name and extract the 5 characters that come after it, i.e. `XX-XX`?

I believe that after finding a way to search for the word `Model` I can use `.substring()` to get the characters I want, but I haven't found an exact way to do that, since the place of the word `Model` doesn't follow a pattern for me can use `-Split`.

Comment: Here's an alt solution: `'File 01 - Vertical - Day 04 - Model 01-01' -match '(?<=Model )\d+-\d+';$Matches[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would go with regex and [named capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3#named-captures) (though note the (in)famous quote - *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."*):

```
PS C:\windows\system32> 'File 02 - Model 01-02 - Day 02' -match 'Model (?<model>\d+-\d+)' 
True 
PS C:\windows\system32> $Matches.model 
01-02
```

Regex - `Model (?<model>\d+-\d+)'`, regex explanation - [@regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uaMZVK/1):

> `Model`  matches the characters Model  literally (case sensitive)
> 1st Capturing Group `(\d+-\d+)`
> `\d` matches a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts (equivalent to \p{Nd})
> `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> `-` matches the character `-` with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)

Comment: It worked perfectly!
I'm going to study the Regex, I have a little trouble understanding them.

Thanks for the tip and detailed explanation.

Comment: @TyroneHirt was glad to help! When/if studying regex I greatly recommend to use the linked regex101 resource - it is a great help.

Comment: I came across regex101 these days and haven't had the opportunity to analyze it better yet, but it looks like a great tool to understand Regex clearly! Thanks a lot for pointing it out.